# Header menu aligned right on all pages except for single-post page

Tags: functions, customization, menus, themes

I have a header with a logo, menu items and a search bar. I have aligned the menu on the right (close to the search bar), but in the 'single-post' page, the menu items appear on the left, starting right after the logo.

The header HTML is the same for each page (I'm getting it using the get_header() function) and the CSS is a single shared file between all components.

I am really dumbfounded here... I've developed the theme myself so maybe I did something to cause this, but I don't really know how it's possible for a completely identical component to appear differently on different pages.

EDIT: I am using the boostrap navbar with the ml-auto class for aligning on the right.

Comment: It's going to be hard to help you to find the code / markup issue without seeing it - any guesses will be just that.

Comment: Figured it out. It was a plugin to which I added some custom css that affected the navbar. Coming from Angular, I thought the plugin css would be contained to the plugin only haha. Silly me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added custom css to a plugin that apparently affected the navbar too.